# Formatting HTML tags in string.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying format some HTML tags in string.xml to use in a TextView. 
When I do format like `<p align="justify">this is my test using HTML in string.xml</p>` doesn't works, in the TextView the text doesn't respect this tag.

How can I do it ?

I'm trying this.

```
//activity
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.apresentation);
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.apresentation)));

//string.xml
<string name="apresentacao">
    <![CDATA[
        <p align="justify">
            The battle of justice was making to who knows learn Lawyer 
            of some way to entertaining and join with your friends.
            The user can begin a Battle Justice and test your wisdom                
        <p>         

        <span>There's 3 arenas</span>
        <ul type="circle">
            <li>Beginner</li>
            <li>Carrier</li>
            <li>Battle Justice</li>             
        </ul>
    ]]>
</string>
```

Comment: so you tried the above approach.... what is the issue then? is it not working.

Comment: yep, isn't works. It's display the HTML but isn't format with `align="justify"` and `type="circle"`

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";
String data ="Hello World"
String txt=String.format(text, data);
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(txt);
txtview.setText(result);
```

You can try this hope it works.